# Custom URL issue in flex ios app

Tags: apache-flex

i am using custom url scheme in my flex iOS app and it’s working fine when i start my app from a web link..but the issue is when i start my app from start menu in iPad and move to webpage in safari.In page i click a button that redirects it to my app, at that time app call “preinitialize” method more than once..it wary every time, some time it’s 2,3,4 and different one each time..i don't know why it’s behaving like this..can i know the reason please its urgent..
thanks…any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a flag `initialized` and set it to `true` when `preinitialize` is called. All other calls to this method can be filtered out. Simple example:

```
private var initialized:Boolean = false;
public function preinitialize():void
{
  if (initialized) return;
  initialized = true;
}
```

Next step would be finding the real cause of the multiple calls, but for that we would need to see some code of your app.

Comment: Thansk for your reply..but i have already tried this solution but never worked..because when i restrict its calling application is crashed..can i get the solution how to prevent its calling of preinitialize..thanks again

Comment: I can't give a concrete solution because I have no idea how your application is coded. You have to show some code if you want more help.